# Using subclass UI hints in a superclass partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

So I've got a partial view that displays a model containing some info for a person at an organization. One of the properties is a list of titles which has a UIHint attribute on it to determine what display template to use for it.
Lets say that the model looks like this:

```
public class Info
{
     [UIHint("Titles")]
     [DataType("Titles")]
     public virtual IEnumerable<string> Titles { get; set; }
}
```

Let's say that the template for Info looks like:

```
@model Info
@Html.DisplayFor(x=> x.Titles)
```

Now we have a very specific type of person-at-org instance that we want to display using the same template but we want to use a different display template for the Titles property so we create a subclass of a Info model:

```
public class SpecificInfo : Info
{
    [UIHint("SpecificTitles")]
    [DataType("SpecificTitles")]
    public override IEnumerable<string> Titles { get; set; }
}
```

But it's still trying to use the "Titles" display template presumably because the expression passed into the DisplayFor helper thinks that it's accessing the property on the Info class.

Is there any way to get that helper to use the correct display template? I've been thinking that a possible solution would be to create my own DisplayFor extension method that figures out what the runtime type of the model is and uses reflection to find the property and check to see if we are specifying a template there but I can't shake the feeling that there might be an easier way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right setting `@model Info` in your view makes `DisplayeFor` use `htmlHelper<Info>`. It has only acces to `Info` attributes. You can spcify in view which template to use:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(x=> x.Titles, Model is SpecificInfo ? "SpecificInfo" : "Info")
```

but then there is no reason for `UIHintAttribute`.

As you write you can also write custom DisplayFor method and you can use `htmlHelper.ViewData.Model` to get actual model attribute(as you suggested in comment ;)):

```
    public static MvcHtmlString CustomDisplayFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
    {
        MemberExpression memberExpression = (MemberExpression)expression.Body;
        var propertyName = memberExpression.Member is PropertyInfo ? memberExpression.Member.Name : (string)null;
        var prop = htmlHelper.ViewData.Model.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
        var customAttributeData = prop.GetCustomAttributesData().FirstOrDefault(a => a.AttributeType.Name == "UIHintAttribute");

        if (customAttributeData != null)
        {
            var templateName = customAttributeData.ConstructorArguments.First().Value as string;
            return DisplayExtensions.DisplayFor<TModel, TValue>(htmlHelper, expression, templateName);
        }
        return DisplayExtensions.DisplayFor<TModel, TValue>(htmlHelper, expression);
    }
```

View:

```
@Html.CustomDisplayFor(x => x.Titles)
```

Comment: You rock! That did the trick. I did make one change where instead of passing in the model I just use the model in htmlHelper.ViewData.Model though

Comment: That great Iidea!! I incude it in answer